# Templates used on each page

Tags: api, templates, sitecore

I have several different subsites using various templates. I need identify the templates used over the entire site. Is there a report or an api call that I can make to my sitecore site? I am new to sitecore. I know the locations of the articles but we have 100s of articles.

Comment: Try posting it on Sitecore stack exchange https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Try posting it on Sitecore stack exchange https://sitecore.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways this can be done. Here are a few options that may be useful depending on your needs:

In the content editor, you can select the root node of your site and click the Search icon next to the Content tab. Perform a blank search and you'll get a faceted search result with each template (See Template section to the right)

Using the Solr UI, you can perform a query where `_path` equals the site root item id. Note that the item id must be all lowercase without braces and dashes. It may be worth rebuilding the master index before doing this, as the index may be outdated.

If your Sitecore instance has Sitecore PowerShell Extensions (SPE) installed, you can simply query the path, such as `Get-ChildItem -Path 'master:/sitecore/content/path/to/site' -Recurse -WithParent` and then chain that result to a simple `Format-Table` or do more fancy stuff with it.

If you want to query a remote machine and play around with local code, you could use SPE remoting (basically the same as above, but from a remote host) or the Sitecore RESTful API for the ItemService (https://doc.sitecore.com/xp/en/developers/93/sitecore-experience-manager/the-restful-api-for-the-itemservice.html). Simply traverse the `https://sitecore-host-name/sitecore/api/ssc/item/{itemid}/children` (after auth).

If you're more into SQL, you could query the `master` database directly, for example `SELECT i.ID, i.Name, i.TemplateID FROM Items i JOIN Descendants d ON i.Id=d.Descendant WHERE d.Ancestor='SiteRootItemId'`. Note that the Sitecore databases are pretty complex and a lot of things are going on in the API layers, so avoid making updates in the database nor write application code talking directly to the database. But for investigation purposes, I think it's fine to query the database. Also, the Descendants table may not be fully up to date, so it's good to perform a "Rebuild Descendants" task on the master database before running such query. It can be done in the admin console at `/sitecore/admin/DBCleanup.aspx`.